# parsing with Mojo::DOM

Tags: perl, mojolicious, mojo

I am using `Mojo::UserAgent->new` to fetch some XML which has the following format:

```
<row>
<td> content1 </td>
<td> content2 </td>
<td> content3 </td>
</row>
<row>
<td> content4 </td>
<td> content5 </td>
<td> content6 </td>
</row>
```

Is it possible to view the results like this:

```
content1,content2,content3
content4,content5,content6
```

below are the query i am using which get different resutls

```
 $ua->get($url)->res->dom->at->(row)->children->each(sub {print "$_\t"})
```

Comment: Please make sure to post real code. The line you posted doesn't even compile. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13293475/1184510) for an explanation why using `at` won't work for you.

Comment: Hello? Are you alive? ;)

Answer (score 5):

Sure, that's absolutely possible and not hard with [Mojo::Collection](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/Collection) working behind the scenes.

**Code**

```
# replace this line by your existing $ua->get($url)->res->dom code
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new(do { local $/ = undef; <DATA> });

# pretty-print rows
$dom->find('row')->each(sub {
    my $row = shift;
    say $row->children->pluck('text')->join(', ');
});
```

**Data**

```
__DATA__
<row>
<td> content1 </td>
<td> content2 </td>
<td> content3 </td>
</row>
<row>
<td> content4 </td>
<td> content5 </td>
<td> content6 </td>
</row>
```

**Output**

```
content1, content2, content3
content4, content5, content6
```

**Some comments**

- **[each](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/Collection#each)** evaluates a code ref for each element of a collection (which is what **[find](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/DOM#find)** returns).
- **[pluck](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/Collection#pluck)** returns a Mojo::Collection object with the return values of the given method name ([text](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/DOM#text) in this case). This is just a fancy way to **[map](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/Collection#map)** simple stuff.
- **[text](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/DOM#text)** automagically trims the element content.
- **[join](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/Collection#join)** joins all elements of the Mojo::Collection object together, all `td` elements of a `row` in this case.
- Your code doesn't even compile, but using **[at](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/DOM#at)** won't work anyway because it returns just the first matching DOM element, not all. You want to iterate *all* rows.

HTH!